# converting an existing angular 5 project to an ionic 3 project

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, wrapper

I was working on an angular 5 project for 3 months and I was building that using Cordova to export android and Ios apps. Now I need some native functionalities for my app but I couldn't find a way to convert or wrap my angular 5 web app to Ionic 3  to use the native abilities of Ionic. Is there any way to convert it easily? without UI changing.

Comment: Ionic and NativeScript are two different frameworks (you are using both tags) - NativeScript provides Angular zero-day support and also has a code-sharing story - still you will need to adjust the UI using the NativeScript controls

Comment: What native abilities you are looking for? How you built your current UI, moving to Ionic 3 may mess with your existing styles so direct Cordova integration might work. NativeScript can't be a choice as the goal here is to keep the UI native to the platform. So you will have to rewrite at least your HTML files with native components.

Comment: I need to remember my username and password and log in automatically and also I want to get push notifications while I'm not using the app, like run app on the background. is there any solution for my requirements in Cordova plugins itself?

Answer (score 6):

The only way I can think of, is by using a new blank Ionic project.

Create the project with the command `ionic start myApp blank`. This will create everything that Ionic & Cordova needs. Then, copy your files into this project manually. Since Ionic uses Angular, you should not have to make major changes.

Comment: what about view changes? All ionic HTML tags are like <ion ...> should I change my HTML files or just copy them.

Comment: Shouldn't be needed. Ionic does have custom html tags, but you don't have to use them.

Comment: what about node_modules? Do they automatically create on build or does cordova has some different packages that are needed to be taken care?

Comment: node_modules isn't created by cordova, its created by npm. It'll get generated as and when packages are installed through npm.

Answer (score 1):

There is no quick way. You need to build from scratch. But there are "shortcuts" and if you done your job well on seperating code and layout, you can significantly speed up the build.